# How to execute sql files using pyhdb?

Tags: python, hana

Is there a way I can use sql script (.sql file) to execute commands via pyhdb? If it is, could someone please let me know?

Answer (score 1):

[PyHDB](https://github.com/SAP/pyhdb/) is a Python library that facilitates accessing a SAP HANA database from a Python program.

To the Python program it provides an API with things like `connections`, `cursors` and `resultsets`.

It does **not** provide functionality to run a `.sql` file (presumably a file containing SQL statements).

What one could do is to use Python to

1. Open the `.sql` file
2. Read the contents of the file and look for **statement separators** (e.g. semicolon)
3. Treat text between statement separators as one single SQL statement and keep them in an array.
4. Close the `.sql` file
5. Use pyHDB to open a connection to HANA.
6. For each statement in the array, create a **cursor**.
7. execute the cursor and retrieve the **result**.
8. Do whatever you want with the result, e.g. print it to the console, save it into another file, just check the return code...
9. Close the cursor
10. Close the connection

That’s it.

Considering that SAP HANA already comes with `hdbsql`, a command line SQL console that can do all this (without Python or pyHDB though), your use case might be different though.